Can someone confirm that this message is normal for an incompatible microSD card?
The first picture below shows what is displayed in the "My Files" app on a Samsung tablet after loading a microSD card into it which is formatted in a filesystem which is incompatible with that particular Android device - APFS -, for example. It says "No SD card", though seemingly it recognizes that one is loaded into the device judging by the GUI of the menu.
It seems a very odd and unclear way of telling the user that the SD card loaded is incompatible with the device.
So, can someone just confirm that this is normal and that this is exactly how the screen should look if you load a microSD card into the device whose filesystem is formatted in an incompatible format?
The second picture just shows my device's details.


